# Selenium chrome Driver upload file and then submit

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

file and then click the submit button 
for some reason after i run the python script .It justs opens the upload window 
and sits there

here is my code .I am using python on windows 10

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = 
       webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://localhost:5000/upload')
element = 

driver.find_element_by_id("uploadfile").send_keys("c:\\projects\\input.xml")
```

modified code --working

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"

driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://localhost:5000/uploadxml')
element = 
driver.find_element_by_id("uploadfile")
.send_keys("c:\\projects\\inout.xml")
click = driver.find_element_by_id("submitfile")
click.click()
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have more than 1 elements with id "uploadfile"?

Comment: Yes I checked it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only select the element. But you don't klick the submit.
Take this code snippet after your select.

```
click = driver.find_element_by_id("**id**")
click.click()
```

Comment: I tried this too same result.I read on stackoverflow that .send_keys also does the same thing